# Update array of object state in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code snippet from my component where I generate Input field according to the objects in the state.

I can successfully generate the input fields but have been getting error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Pointing to the method `arrayObjToArrary` in **Utils.js** whenever I type in the input field.

How can I update the value of here ??

**Main.js**

```js
import Input from "../UI/Input";
import {arrayObjToArrary} from "../../utility/Utils.js";

const [profiles, setProfiles] = useState({
    controls: [
      {
        network: {
          elementType: "input",
          elementConfig: {
            type: "text",
            label: "Network",
          },
          value: "Twitter",
        },
      },
      {
        username: {
          elementType: "input",
          elementConfig: {
            type: "text",
            label: "Username",
          },
          value: "@john",
        },
      },
      {
        url: {
          elementType: "input",
          elementConfig: {
            type: "url",
            label: "URL",
          },
          value: "https://example.xyz",
        },
      },
    ],
  });
  
  const profilesControls = arrayObjToArrary(profiles.controls);
  const arrayInputHandler = (event, index, identifier) => {
    const list = [...profiles.controls];
    list[index][identifier] = event.target.value;
    setProfiles(list);
  };
  
  let profileField = profilesControls.map((formElement) => (
    <Input
      label={formElement.config.elementConfig.label}
      key={formElement.index}
      type={formElement.config.elementType}
      elementConfig={formElement.config.elementConfig}
      value={formElement.config.value}
      changed={(event) => arrayInputHandler(event, formElement.index, formElement.id)}
    />
  ));
```

**Utils.js**

```js
export const arrayObjToArrary = (controls) => {
  const formElementsArray = controls.map((item,index) =>({
    id: Object.keys(item)[0],
    index:index,
    config: item[Object.keys(item)[0]],
  }))
  return formElementsArray;
}
```

Comment: can you show what this is? `arrayObjToArrary` also rename to `arrayObjToArray` otherwise it'll confuse you going forward

Comment: before map check the result of ```profilesControls``` in console

Answer (score 1):

The issue in how you update your profiles object in `arrayInputHandler`. When you pass in the list to setProfiles, it changes its structure from an object to array.

Also you must not mutate the original state values. The correct way to update is as below

```
const arrayInputHandler = (event, index, identifier) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setProfiles(prev => ({
        ...prev,
        controls: profiles.controls.map((controls, i) => {
           if(i === index) {
              return {
                ...controls, [identifier]: {
                  ...controls[identifier],
                  value
               }
              }
           }
           return controls
        });
    }));
  };
```

P.S. You can always solve your problem in a simplistic manner like

```
const arrayInputHandler = (event, index, identifier) => {
    const list = [...profiles.controls];
    list[index][identifier] = event.target.value;
    setProfiles({profile:list});
  };
```

However its not a correct approach and should be avoided as react relies a lot on immutability for a lot of its re-rendering and other optimizations

Comment: Thank you for your answer but with your snippet  I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined` error

Comment: I don't see label being used in the above code snippet. Anyways I have updated my answers

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
const arrayInputHandler = (event, index, identifier) => {
    const list = [...profiles.controls];
    list[index][identifier].value = event.target.value;
    setProfiles({ controls: list });
};
```

check here [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-robinson-qwtoj?file=/src/App.js:1055-1251)